# MVC5 Typeahead Feature

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, typeahead.js

I have created a basic typeahead and it works ok but looks pretty rubbish.

I want to create something more like this: http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/

Anyone know of where I can find an example of this nature?

Comment: Example? typeahead is opensource isnt it?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm not sure how to add the icons and make it look

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm not sure how to add the icons and make it look nice.

Comment: Do you want an exact look and feel? If so, start looking at the css files that typeahead already has. If you want a different one, start working on some design. Either way, you will have to learn CSS